# ValueError: No 'serving_default' in the SavedModel's SignatureDefs. Possible values are ''

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I have .data, .index and .meta, I was able to create saved_model.pb and a variable holder form a TensorFlow script.

When I run the following command,

```
tflite_convert --output_file='/home/tensor/Work/cr/saved.tflite' --saved_model_dir='/home/tensor/Work/cr/model_out'
```

It gives me error

```
ValueError: No 'serving_default' in the SavedModel's SignatureDefs. Possible values are ''.
```

I would like to convert this .pb file to .tflite. Can someone please tell me how to solve this error?

Comment: Can you give some details about the commands you run to obtain the Saved Model? We need an 'inference' graph for conversion to tflite, which doesn't seem to be present in your saved model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an 'inference graph' to convert to TFLite.

For that, you need to export a graph that has all the variables converted to constants (since TFLite won't really be doing any training). The instructions for this conversion are [here](https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc), specifically this snippet of code:

```
import os, argparse

import tensorflow as tf

# The original freeze_graph function
# from tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph import freeze_graph 

dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

def freeze_graph(model_dir, output_node_names):
    """Extract the sub graph defined by the output nodes and convert 
    all its variables into constant 
    Args:
        model_dir: the root folder containing the checkpoint state file
        output_node_names: a string, containing all the output node's names, 
                            comma separated
    """
    if not tf.gfile.Exists(model_dir):
        raise AssertionError(
            "Export directory doesn't exists. Please specify an export "
            "directory: %s" % model_dir)

    if not output_node_names:
        print("You need to supply the name of a node to --output_node_names.")
        return -1

    # We retrieve our checkpoint fullpath
    checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_dir)
    input_checkpoint = checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path

    # We precise the file fullname of our freezed graph
    absolute_model_dir = "/".join(input_checkpoint.split('/')[:-1])
    output_graph = absolute_model_dir + "/frozen_model.pb"

    # We clear devices to allow TensorFlow to control on which device it will load operations
    clear_devices = True

    # We start a session using a temporary fresh Graph
    with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
        # We import the meta graph in the current default Graph
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta', clear_devices=clear_devices)

        # We restore the weights
        saver.restore(sess, input_checkpoint)

        # We use a built-in TF helper to export variables to constants
        output_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess, # The session is used to retrieve the weights
            tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(), # The graph_def is used to retrieve the nodes 
            output_node_names.split(",") # The output node names are used to select the usefull nodes
        ) 

        # Finally we serialize and dump the output graph to the filesystem
        with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
            f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
        print("%d ops in the final graph." % len(output_graph_def.node))

    return output_graph_def
```